# Playing mp4, flv files in UIWebview, Webkit

Tags: ios

I am trying to load and open a video file of format mp4 or flv in UIWebview. But whenever I try to open it, there are actually 4 network calls being made for an mp4 file that I see on my Web Debugging Proxy Tool, with the first file request Content Range being of only 2 bytes, and all other 3 subsequent requests of proper Range. I tried this with Webkit, and with different sized mp4 videos available on the web, result was the same as well. So is this an expected behaviour for the web view to make 4 calls with the first being of only 2 bytes. This at times is making my video appear with a strike out, and the video is not playable